# counting values and adding reference in a new dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that contains multiple appearances of a certain value in a certain column. I want to set those values unique by adding some kind of a reference in a new column. for example, suppose i have a dataframe with an ID column:

```
          ID
7     2035200584
8     2035200584
9     2035200584
31    2038128459
32    2038128459
33    2038128459
42    2053561908
43    2053561908
44    2053561908
```

and I want to create a new column, say "newID", which will look something like this:

```
          ID
7     2035200584_1
8     2035200584_2
9     2035200584_3
31    2038128459_1
32    2038128459_2
33    2038128459_3
42    2053561908_1
43    2053561908_2
44    2053561908_3
```

Iv'e tried to use the groupby mechanism, but with no success. using the simple apply mechanism is ok, but seems a little cumbersome (I'll need to keep a dictionary containing a counter of appearances for each ID)

Is there a simple and efficient way to do that that I'm missing?

Comment: @DSM: I was going to delete my solution, since yours seems to perform significantly better than mine. Would you please undelete yours?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a slight variation of DSM's solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

content = io.BytesIO('''index ID
7     2035200584
8     2035200584
9     2035200584
31    2038128459
32    2038128459
33    2038128459
42    2053561908
43    2053561908
44    2053561908''')

df = pd.read_table(content, sep='\s+', header=0)

df['ID'] = df.groupby('ID')['ID'].transform(
    lambda x: map('{:.0f}_{:.0f}'.format, x, x.rank('first')))

print(df)
```

yields

```
   index            ID
0      7  2035200584_1
1      8  2035200584_2
2      9  2035200584_3
3     31  2038128459_1
4     32  2038128459_2
5     33  2038128459_3
6     42  2053561908_1
7     43  2053561908_2
8     44  2053561908_3
```

Comment: Can you explain what is happing here? because i was trying to use groupby and apply and what i got back was a series with the ID as index and the modified ID's as lists for each index. what is going on here under the hood? what is the translation into natural language of the code above?

Comment: `apply` and `transform` do similar things. `apply` is a complicated beast because it behaves differently depending on the type of object the function returns. I have not attempted to memorize [the rules which govern this behavior](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/groupby.py#L330), I simply try a few plausible variations until I find the one that works. In this case, since I knew transform is intended for changing a Series to another Series *of equal length*, I tried transform.

Comment: To better understand what my solution is doing, I suggest first looking at `df.groupby('ID')['ID'].transform(lambda x: x)` then `df.groupby('ID')['ID'].transform(lambda x: x.rank('first'))` and `map('{}_{}'.format, [1,2,3], 'abc')`. If you understand those pieces, then I suspect you'll understand my solution, at least on the level I understand it.